# Deleting a specific element from a list of cards in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to delete a specific element in the list of cards that I return. But when I try to delete a specific card, it always deletes the last added card in the list. For example, I have an assortment of cards: [Tesla, Facebook, Google, Amazon]. I then add a new card, which updates the assortment of cards to [Tesla, Facebook, Google, Amazon, Microsoft]. I want to delete "Tesla" from the list, but I end up deleting "Microsoft" instead.

For some reason, I always end up referencing the last item in the array of objects when I try to delete something. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
const displayApplications = (props) => {
  const {applications} = props;

  const deleteApplicationHandler = async (id) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}`,
      },
    };

    try {
      axios.delete(`api/applications/deleteApplication/${id}`, config);

      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.response.data.error);
    }
  };

  if (applications.length > 0) {
    return applications.map((application, id) => {
      const formattedDate = moment(application.dateApplied).format('MM-DD-YY');

      return (
        <>
          <Card variant="outlined" style={{height: '250px', width: '300px'}} key={application._id}>
            <CardHeader
              action={
                <IconButton color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
                  <MoreVertIcon fontSize="large" />
                </IconButton>
              }
              avatar={
                <Avatar
                  src={application.companyLogo}
                  aria-label={`company-logo`}
                  style={{width: '55px', height: '55px'}}
                />
              }
              title={application.company}
              subheader={`Applied on: ${formattedDate}`}
              classes={{
                title: classes.headerTitle,
              }}
            />
            <Menu
              elevation={1}
              id="basic-menu"
              anchorEl={anchorEl}
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
              style={{shadows: 'none'}}
              MenuListProps={{
                'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
              }}>
              <MenuItem onClick={() => deleteApplicationHandler(application._id)}>
                Delete Application
              </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
            <CardContent style={{paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: '25px', paddingRight: '25px'}}>
              <Typography variant="h5" component="div" style={{fontColor: ''}}>
                {application.position}
              </Typography>
              <Typography style={{mb: 1.5}} color="text.secondary">
                {application.status}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2">{application.comments}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </>
      );
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>No applications yet </h3>
      </>
    );
  }
};
```

Controller code for the deleteApplicationHandler:

```
deleteApplication = async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;

    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    }

    if (!token) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse("Not authorized to access this route", 401));
    }

    try {
        // getting user's information
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

        const user = await User.findById(decoded.id);

        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse("No user found with this id", 404));
        }

        req.user = user;

        const application = await Application.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);

        console.log(application);

        res.status(200).json({ message: `Application for ${user.username} at ${application.company} has been deleted`, application });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. How does the back-end for `api/applications/deleteApplication/${id}` look? And are your sure that the ids are unique?

Comment: what is the response of calling delete API? do you check it on the network tab?

Comment: It would be super helpful to see what the data structure looks like, and the logic within the controller. The front end is passing the ID to delete just fine.

Comment: @Erik just updated the question with the backend code for the deleteApplicationHandler. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: @novonimo when testing in Postman, calling the delete API will result in the removal of a card using its id.

Comment: @JuanChaher just updated the question with the backend code, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Is the backend deleting the correct application? You could also try to get the applications ,after the delete, instead of window.location.reload().

Answer (score 0):

The root element returned for your render function under `applications.map` returns a fragment `<>` and it doesn't have a key, therefore, React doesn't know which of the elements matches your array elements, it just notices you are now trying to render less elements than you did before, so removing the last one should be good enough. In your case, it isn't.

If you just remove the `<>` and it's matching closing tag `</>`, React will be able to see the `key` prop in `<Card key={application._id}>`.

Another option would be to use `<React.Fragment key={application._id}>` (and it's matching closing tag instead of `<>`.